# Properties preserved in addition of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals, radicals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If I and J are prime (radical) ideals then what are the conditions under which we can define a prime (radical) ideal from I+J?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.